# Android: Reset Activity onClick

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity and on that activity there are a couple of buttons that do different things with numbers, etc. At a certain point though I would like to be able to have the user reset/(restart?) the activity back to the initial state without having the user have to hit the back button or restart the app.

I want to create a reset button. I know how to make the button itself, but I do not the details of how to reset the activity.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // do stuff
    break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // do stuff
        break;      
    case R.id.button3:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case R.id.reset:
        // what goes here?
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

How is this done?

Comment: what you mean by reset? Do elaborate.

Comment: I mean I would like the activity to go back to its original state (i.e. counters returning back to zero, etc.) Is there something special or are the variables and stuff just re-initialized back to 0/whatever else I want in that case of the switch?

Comment: See my answer. It will restart the activity. Not sure if thats what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will restart your activity.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // do stuff
    break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // do stuff
        break;      
    case R.id.button3:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case R.id.reset:
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent);    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

You can add  the following to get rid of the  fancy animations.

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

Comment: I have four buttons currently with the addition of the reset. With the three buttons, the enabling/disabling worked perfectly. With the addition of the reset button with this code, it has permanently disabled one of the buttons, even though in the other cases it is set to be enabled. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: This is a weird behavior. Can not tell unless I see the relevant source code. Can you start a new question and post the code and the problem?

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute to get it posted.

Comment: I have posted the question with the relevant code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813626/android-reset-button-permanently-disabled-another-button