# Android: Reset Button Permanently Disabled Another Button

Tags: android, android-activity

I currently have four buttons. The fourth button is a reset button I added to reset the activity to the state when it was originally started. However, when I added the reset button it disabled one of the buttons permanently, even though previously, the buttons were being enabled/disabled the way they were supposed to. Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

    // non relevant code

    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    changeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_button);
    changeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    nextButton.setEnabled(false);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    reset.setEnabled(false);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ok:
        changeButton.setEnabled(false);
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
        break;

    case R.id.change_button:
        changeButton.setEnabled(false);
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
        break;

    case R.id.next_button:
        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        okButton.setEnabled(true);
        changeButton.setEnabled(true);
        break;

    case R.id.reset:
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Everything was working as it should have until all of the parts involving the reset button were added. Essentially, the behaviour I want is:

- Initially: next and reset are disabled, they become enabled when either change or ok are clicked
- When either change or ok are clicked, they both are disabled (to prevent clicking more than once) and both reset and next are enabled
- When next or reset are clicked, they become disabled and change and ok become enabled.

The change, ok, and next button behaviors were working until the reset code was added. Then the next button became permanently disabled. What is wrong? How do I fix it?

EDIT*:

Here is the xml code for the buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/change_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/change_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/reset"
    android:text="@string/Ok" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/change_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/change_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/next_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/reset" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/change_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/next_button"
    android:text="@string/change" />
```

Comment: Your code works in my emulator. I just think you missed enabling, disabling reset button in switch cases.

Comment: I don't like that you call something after finish(); no idea how that would behave... you should reset properly, not relaunch activity.

Comment: How to fix? That solution was something given to me in another question. (see the linked question)

Comment: @Warpzit, he wants to restart the activity.

Comment: @lord_sneed, are you testing this on a device? Clean the project and run again.

Comment: @LazyNinja but if he want to restart it he should just call startActivity() add a bundle and handle it properly.

Comment: @Shreya Shah This code is not working for me in my emulator.

Comment: @Warpzit, without the finish, the activity will remain in the task.

Comment: @LazyNinja I do not have a device. The emulator is the best/only thing I have at the moment. I am hoping to get an actual device around the holidays.

Comment: @lord_sneed, comment out the finish() line and see how it will behave.

Comment: @LazyNinja not if he uses android:launchMode "singleTask" or "singleInstance" in the activity tag of the manifest.

Comment: @Warpzit, Thanks! I havent thought about that.

Comment: @lord_sneed Next button works fine in my emulator with the given code.

Comment: @LazyNinja Commenting out the finish() line changes nothing.

Comment: @lord_sneed, this should work. Can you post the activity_name.xml code so I can try it on my device. This way I could take all the bugs.

Comment: @LazyNinja I posted the xml for the buttons. It is in a relative layout and it has some other aspects (TextViews), which I did not post.

Comment: @LazyNinja I managed to get it working. I think it had issues with some of the naming. I had a button variable name called 'reset' and then the id was also 'reset'. So I changed the id to 'resetButton' and made the corresponding changes to onClick() and onCreate()

Comment: @lord_sneed, glad it works. I have just posted an answer lol.

Comment: @LazyNinja Is there a way I can just ask you directly next time I have a question? You seem pretty talented (not that no one else is) and I am very much a beginner (the app I am creating being the first one aside from "Hello Android", basic button tests, etc. and I know that I will need the help lol.

Comment: @lord_sneed, there is the chat room but you dont have enough reputations yet. Will try to help by upvoting your posts.

Comment: @LazyNinja Ok. I suppose in the meantime, I will just continue to ask the community. I am so glad the stackoverflow community exists :)

Comment: @lord_sneed I give a very good website to know the ins and outs of android: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

Comment: @lord_sneed Have you checked solution I have posted for your problem?

Comment: @PratikSharma I have not, but it looks like it does exactly the same thing. I will implement a method like that in the next app I do. I currently have finished the app I was currently working on (except for altering the theme, which I am trying to figure out) and so I would rather not mess with it. I will upvote your answer though if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Initially: next and reset are disabled, they become enabled when
>   either change or ok are clicked

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ok:
        changeButton.setEnabled(false);
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
        reset.setEnabled(true); // add this
        break;

    case R.id.change_button:
        changeButton.setEnabled(false);
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
        reset.setEnabled(true); // add this
        break;

    case R.id.next_button:
        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        okButton.setEnabled(true);
        changeButton.setEnabled(true);
       reset.setEnabled(false); // add this
        break;

    case R.id.reset:
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This worked for me/ Add those lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow in this way, which helps you for good Programming practices.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ok:
        setButtonStates(false,false,true,true);
        break;

    case R.id.change_button:
        setButtonStates(false,false,true,true);
        break;

    case R.id.next_button:
        setButtonStates(true,true,false,false);
        break;

    case R.id.reset:
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void setButtonStates(boolean flag1, boolean flag2, boolean flag3, boolean flag4){
    changeButton.setEnabled(flag1);
    okButton.setEnabled(flag2);
    nextButton.setEnabled(flag3);
    reset.setEnabled(flag4);
}
```

This way your code looks clear and easy to modify on need.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want please comment if any changes you want

```
//Buttons
    Button okButton,changeButton,resetButton,nextButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // non relevant code

        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        changeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeButton);
        changeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setEnabled(false);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.okButton:
            changeButton.setEnabled(false);
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
            nextButton.setEnabled(true);
            resetButton.setEnabled(true);
            break;

        case R.id.changeButton:
            changeButton.setEnabled(false);
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
            nextButton.setEnabled(true);
            resetButton.setEnabled(true);
            break;

        case R.id.nextButton:
            nextButton.setEnabled(false);
            resetButton.setEnabled(false);
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
            changeButton.setEnabled(true);
            break;

        case R.id.resetButton:
            resetButton.setEnabled(false);
            nextButton.setEnabled(false);
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
            changeButton.setEnabled(true);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```